# How to detect slide direction in Slick Carousel onBeforeChange?

Tags: jquery, carousel, direction

How can I know what direction the carousel are going on the event `onBeforeChange`. right or left?

```
    $('.foo').slick
        infinite: false
        onBeforeChange: (e) ->
            if right
                do_this()
            if left
                do_that()
```

[Slick Carousel](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/)

Answer (score 13):

beforeChange event get you an access to **currentSlide** and **nextSlide** values.

It works for infinite sliders too.

So, the code is:

```
$(".some-element").on('beforeChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  if (Math.abs(nextSlide - currentSlide) == 1) {
    direction = (nextSlide - currentSlide > 0) ? "right" : "left";
  }
  else {
    direction = (nextSlide - currentSlide > 0) ? "left" : "right";
  }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work for infinite slider sadly. Going from the first to the last slide the direction should be left; result of the code above is right.

Comment: Great answer :)

Comment: It does work for inifnite slider. I just tested it

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ended up doing. It can probably be written simpler, but it works. This is called during the `beforeChange` event. This works for infinite scroll.

```
if (currentSlide === 0 && nextSlide === slick.$slides.length - 1) {
    // its going from the first slide to the last slide (backwards)
    direction = 'prev';
} else if (nextSlide > currentSlide || (currentSlide === (slick.$slides.length - 1) && nextSlide === 0 )) {
    // its either going normally forwards or going from the last slide to the first
    direction = 'next';
} else {
    direction = 'prev';
}
```

Comment: Please mention that it doesn't work with default "slidesToScroll" option. To fix this you need to change "1" to same count as you have in "slidesToScroll".  So if you have "slidesToScroll: 3" change "slick.$slides.length - 1" to "slick.$slides.length - 3"

Answer (score 2):

this works for me when infinite:true  when beforeChange event triggers.

```
var dir;
if((currentSlide<nextSlide&&currentSlide==nextSlide-1)||(currentSlide==slick.slideCount-1&&nextSlide==0))
      {
           dir='right';
      }
else if(nextSlide<currentSlide||(nextSlide==slick.slideCount-1&&currentSlide==0))
      {
         dir='left';
      }
if(dir=='right')
{
//do something.
}
if(dir=='left')
{
//do something.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to ask if the element has the dir attribute and is set to rtl

```
    var attr = $('.foo').attr('dir');
    if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false && attr === 'rtl') {
      do_this()
    } else {
      do_that()
    }
```

Comment: what does a console.log on attr prints?

Answer (score -1):

beforeChange event handlers accept currentSl,ide and nextSlide arguments

```
$(el).slick().on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    if(currentSlide < nextSlide){
        console.log('forward');
    } else{
        console.log('back');
    }
});
```

Comment: I had thought the same, but unfortunately this won't work when the carousel loops, as the nextSlide would be less than the currentSlide.

Comment: or when you attempt to drag slides and stop in the middle. then currentslide == next slide